# Service bean failed to inject in spring cglib proxy

Tags: java, proxy, spring-aop, cglib

I have an annotation

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface PartnerProxy {
}
```

And a Advice

```
@Component
@Aspect
public class AnnotationAdvice {

    @Around("@annotation(PartnerProxy)")
    public Object pc(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        return joinPoint.proceed();
    }
}
```

And the bean i want to proxy

```
public class OuterServiceProxy {

    private IRoomStatusService service;
    ... another properties

    String getRemoteHourRoomStatus(){
        return service.echo();
    }
    @PartnerProxy
    public void hello() {
    }
    ...getters & setters
```

there is a property `IRoomStatusService service`, which is the point.
firstly if i declare  `OuterServiceProxy` in spring xml file

```
<bean id="outerServiceProxy" class="aop.jg.OuterServiceProxy">
        <property name="service" ref="service"/>
    </bean>
```

and when `outerServiceProxy.getRemoteHourRoomStatus()` method is called, An NPE was thrown. I debug to that line [1]

```
String getRemoteHourRoomStatus(){
        return service.echo();  [1]
    }
```

`service` is null. But `outerServiceProxy` is `OuterServiceProxy$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$b0b63bb6` actually enhanced by Cglib, but it seems `outerServiceProxy` just call `String getRemoteHourRoomStatus()` directly  and not through callback and call TargetSource, So `service` is null. But that make no sense!

When i add public modifier, `public String getRemoteHourRoomStatus()` everything goes fine.

And even more strange thing is that without `public` modifer, same code goes well in my PC, but NPE thrown in company testing environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the trick: The VM only consideres a package-private method to be overridden if the overriding class is loaded by the same `ClassLoader` as the class the defines the overridden method.

This means that for two classes with overridden package-private methods such as:

```
public class Foo { String qux() { return "foo"; } }
public class Bar extends Foo { @Override String qux() { return "bar"; } }
```

where

```
Foo.class.getClassLoader() != Bar.class.getClassLoader()
```

holds, the following behavior can be observed:

```
Foo foo = new Bar();
assertThat(foo.qux(), is("foo"));
assertThat(((Bar) foo).qux(), is("bar"));
```

The reasoning is that the runtime packages are not equal and therefore, the package-private methods of differing runtime packages do not override one another. This is less a limitation of cglib than a specification detail of the JVM.