# write java object into class file

Tags: java, proxy, bytecode, cglib

Is there any way to write a loaded Java object into a `.class` file or is there any other type of file that can easily be read to represent an instance's properties.

For example, CGLIB will create an proxy bean which extends another, i really want to export this enhanced bean out to a `file` to see how it was enhanced.

Comment: You can use reflection APIs to analyze the java runtime object instance https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/

Comment: cglib source code - https://github.com/cglib/cglib

Comment: You can serialize java objects into json string or stream and deserialize using gson.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For cglib, instances can only be serialized and only if the instance's method interceptors support serialization. There is no other way.

In order to get hold of a cglib-generated class file, you can call the

```
void generateClass(ClassVisitor v)
```

method. This method can take an ASM `ClassWriter` which can after calling the method emitt a byte array representing the class file. This class file by itself does however not help you much as cglib needs to initialize the class explicitly, e.g. inject the callback handlers into the class's fields. This is done inside of the library. However, with the class file at hand and with debug-mode introspection, you can add the pieces and understand how your enhanced class works.

Finally, if I can recommend you an alternative to cglib where all this is easier, have a look at [Byte Buddy](https://github.com/raphw/byte-buddy) which has a straight-foward API for extracting a class file and also offers so-called `LoadedTypeInitializer`s in parallel to this class file. The latter initializers contain any setup logic for a class and are easy to read. Also, they are themselfs serializable.

Comment: Thanks,  so forget object instance. Is there any way to just write `enhanced class` generated by `generateClass()` out into `.class` file?

Comment: Pass a `ClassWriter` as an argument. Afterwards, call `toByteArray` on the writer and a `byte[]` array representing the class file is returned.

Comment: But you need a `ClassReader` first,  however `ClassReader` constructor need class `byte[]` data. But what i have is just `Class<?> aClass = CglibEnhancedProxy.class`. I don't know how to convert `aClass` to `byte[]`.

Comment: Not a `ClassReader`, you need a `ClassWriter` - note the **Writer**.

Comment: Oh, i understand it. But it seems doesn't do much help. Because this question is linked to [A Spring AOP Strange Problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35135499/service-bean-failed-to-inject-in-spring-cglib-proxy), So it looks hard to get the enhancer.

Comment: @RafaelWinterhalter To be fair, I think you should mention that you are the developer of ByteBuddy

Comment: I should, you are right. Then again, I am also maintaining cglib.

Answer (score 3):

to use HSDB tool in JDK

1. keep your program running
2. run HSDB tool:

   java -classpath "$JAVA_HOME/lib/sa-jdi.jar" sun.jvm.hotspot.HSDB
3. input the program pid
   [image]
4. choose tools and you can save .class file,that is what you want
   [image]

Comment: Maybe it's worth to mention that the saved class files are stored in the current directory as `your/package/TheClass.class`.